# Php function to save a image

Tags: php, image, function, save

I have some images used for the avatars of the users on my website, for example http://drksde.tk/images/avatar-Luxie.jpeg
I want to add a link that allow the users to download the avatar image, when someone click in the link a Save As dialog should appear.

---

Now the problem is that the picture is not downloaded properly, but the dialog appears, here is the link to [download the avatar](http://drksde.tk/images/user-Luxie.jpeg), and the code:

```
<?php
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $size = $_GET['size'];
    $ext = $_GET['ext'];
    $border = $_GET['border'];
    $basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if(!isset($size)) { $size = 'small'; }
    if(!isset($ext)) { $ext = 'jpeg'; }
    if(!isset($border)) { $border = 'true'; }

$file = 'avatar-'.$size.'-'.$username.'.'.$ext;

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$basename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    #header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Of course, they can always simply right-click on the image and "save as"

Comment: typically an avatar link would take you to the user's profile page. changing it to a "download the image" kind of breaks the point of having an avatar in the first place. I'd suggest leaving it as a link to a profile, then put an explicit "download this image" link on the profile page.

Comment: @mark-b I know, the site works like that, I'm asking about how to make the "download this image" link, to show an Save As dialog when the users clicks it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you any relevant code that you have problems with?

Comment: I don't tried anyhing, because I didn't found anything of help.

1. I have a picture, http://drksde.tk/images/avatar-Luxie.png for example.

2. I want to put a link on the website, something like "Download your avatar" that shows a Save As dialog when clicked, like when you try to download a file, but with a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out **Example #1** in the php.net manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

It shows how to force an image download.

You could place it into a script `image.php` and use it like this

```
 <a href="http://example.com/image.php?user=123">download avatar image</a>
```

You could use it with the `$_GET['user']` parameter to serve the right user image file.

Just remember to validate the GET input.